# Detach COM events using pywin32

Tags: python, events, com, pywin32

Is it possible to detach a specific event after attaching it to a COM object?

For example, how to deregister the `ClassOfHandlers` in the following snippet:

```py
from win32com.client import WithEvents

# ...

class ClassOfHandlers():
  def OnStart(self):
    print("Start observed")

class AnotherClassOfHandlers():
  def OnStart(self):
    print("Start observed from another")

WithEvents(client, ClassOfHandlers)
# ...
WithEvents(client, AnotherClassOfHandlers)
# ...
# Deregister `ClassOfHandlers`
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Based on [DS_London's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73883884/2730737) we could benefit from `WithEvents` return, thus the combined solution would look like

```
from win32com.client import WithEvents

def MyOnStart():
  print("Start observed")

def MySecondOnStart():
  print("Start observed from another")

class ClassOfHandlers():
  def __init__(self):
    self._onStarts = []
    # self._onStops = []
    # ... add a list of functions for each event type

  # the following 3 methods are implemented for each event type
  def attachStart(self, fn):
    self._onStarts.append(fn)

  def detachStart(self, fn):
    self._onStarts.remove(fn)

  def OnStart(self):
    for fn in self._onStarts:
      fn()

# Always at the beginning
handler = WithEvents(client, ClassOfHandlers)

handler.attachStart(MyOnStart)
# ...
handler.attachStart(MySecondOnStart)
# ...
handler.detachStart(MyOnStart)
```

##### Limitation

If support for multiple clients is needed and thus threading is used, this edit won't work, and **it would be needed to use the original answer's approach**.

The cause: one needs to pass the `ClassOfHandlers` to the thread runnable*, however the thread runnable would `PumpWaitingMessages()` till interrupted, thus it won't be able to return the client handler back, preventing us from being able to detach/attach further functions while waiting for messages.

* `PumpWaitingMessages()` requires that it runs on the same thread that connected the `ClassOfHandlers` to the `client`, thus we can't create the client handler out of the thread then send it into the thread runnable.

Following is a snippet that shows this scenario:

```
def threadRunnable(client, eventsClass, controller):
  pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)

  # Connect the custom events
  # The connection needs to be done inside the same thread for PumpWaitingMessages
  handler = WithEvents(client, eventsClass)

  if controller == None:
    print("no control was provided")
    controller = { "sleep_time": 1, "running_flag": True}

  # With this while we won't be able to return the handler
  while controller["running_flag"]:
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
    time.sleep(controller["sleep_time"])
  pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

def connectEvents(client, eventsClass, controller=None, runnable=threadRunnable):
  flusher = Thread(target=runnable, args=(client,eventsClass,controller))
  flusher.daemon = True
  flusher.start()

def main():
  controller = { "sleep_time": 1, "running_flag": True}
  connectEvents(client, ClassOfHandlers, controller)
```

---

### Original

I'm now able to achieve the desired behavior, by attaching a single permanent observer class and managing the events myself.

For example:

```py
from win32com.client import WithEvents

# ...

class ClassOfHandlers():
  OnStarts = []
  def OnStart(self):
    for handler in ClassOfHandlers.OnStarts:
      handler()

def MyOnStart():
  print("Start observed")

def MySecondOnStart():
  print("Start observed from another")

# Always at the beginning
WithEvents(client, ClassOfHandlers)

ClassOfHandlers.OnStarts.append(MyOnStart)
# ...
ClassOfHandlers.OnStarts.append(MySecondOnStart)
# ...
ClassOfHandlers.OnStarts.remove(MyOnStart)
```

Hint:
The class variable `OnStarts` shall be changed to an instance variable if the class represents an instantiable COM object, to allow having an instance of the `ClassOfHandlers` (each instance having a different handler list) for each instantiated COM object.

One also needs to ensure that `WithEvents` is called only once for each COM object instance.

Answer (score 1):

As a variation on the OP's answer, which avoids a static member variable, it is worth remembering that `WithEvents()` returns an instance of the handler class.

```
from win32com.client import WithEvents

def MyOnStart():
  print("Start observed")

def MySecondOnStart():
  print("Start observed from another")

class ClassOfHandlers():
  def __init__(self):
      self._fn = MyOnStart

  def setStartFunction(self,fn):
      self._fn = fn

  def OnStart(self):
      self._fn()

handler = WithEvents(client, ClassOfHandlers)

#then later

handler.setStartFunction(MySecondOnStart)
```

Hence you can re-use the handler class for a different `client`.

Alternatively you could try opening an issue [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues) and maybe the developers can advise on whether they expose the [IConnectionPoint::Unadvise()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ocidl/nf-ocidl-iconnectionpoint-unadvise) function which would be needed behind the scenes to switch event handlers (I think).

Comment: The handler being returned is a great hint, using that the solution could be greatly cleaned, I'm adding how both approaches could be combined as an edit.

Comment: And here is the [link to the opened issue](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1952)